# Obtain failed joined requests on multitech conduit gateway aep model

Tags: gateway, lora, lorawan

I'm currently trying to connect a device using a sx1276 to a multitech conduit gateway: aep model. I'm unable to join the gateway and I'm looking for a way to see the log of the failed attempts to find what might be causing it to fail.

Is it possible to find that information on the gateway? What are my options to debug a device that is emitting( can see it on spectrometer) but not joining a gateway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to your Conduit web GUI, under Setup > LoRa Network Server, set

Log Destination: **FILE**

Path: **/var/log/lora-network-server.log**

Log level: **MAXIMUM**

Then go to your Conduit's Linux system, enter
**tail -f /var/log/lora-network-server.log**

You will be able to see packages that hit the gateway.

Also, enter **lora-query -n** will help you to see a lot of useful information.

If you want to debug your device, please provide your device information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Top.Deck, I'll play around with this and see what I can come up with. I've been doing some testing with a multitech mdot box and now trying to see what causes our own device, implementing a sx1276 to be unable to join the gateway.

Comment: If your mDot works fine, I'd like to suggest a Ping-Pong test for your own devices to make sure the LoRa transmitting procedure is working properly.

Comment: When I use tail lora-network-server.log I can see that I receive an unconfirmed up frame when I launch my device.  So I'm fairly confident it's transmitting correctly . I do get a MessageRejectException : Message received from unknown node. I'm guessing I simply have some settings that are wrong to join the gateway and it's rejecting the packet because of it.